# Regex replace with preservation

Tags: regex, vb.net, replace, integer, match

I want to replace a string in Visual Basic .NET, More specifically integers in a VB.NET script.

I'm using this method to recognize integers:

```
[^"](,|=|\/|\+|\-|\(|) (\d+)(\)|)[^"]
```

As you can see in the following Rubular test, it identifies normal integers and doesn't include the ones found in names, etc. Though I still have some problems identifying them.

Here's the test: http://rubular.com/r/q019lCUS45

---

Basically, what I want to do is add CInt(\d+) to all integers in a string of Visual Basic.NET script. So that it looks like this before:

```
Dim I As Integer = 0
```

And like this after:

```
Dim I As Integer = CInt(0)
```

[image: Rubular]

Comment: Your regex selects all kinds of things but it does not select integers.

Comment: It looks for integers with either , = / + or ( before them

Comment: Okay I fixed my regex, I went to the fridge to get some food and it hit me - http://rubular.com/r/rGzbCUkGPo

Though I still need a way to replace them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why aren't you using word boundaries? It removes for you the "numbers" that are surrounded by letters.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lB3yQ7)

`/\b(\d+)\b/CInt(\1)` With this regex, it'll search all numbers and replace them by CInt(NUMBER)

Comment: How would I execute this on the Visual Basic script then?